# Mozilla addon configuration through web site

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I need to allow user to configure my addon setting though web site. In the first run it redirect to the web site, though my web page user can configure it settings.( Ex: WOT).

Is there any specific way to implement this one?

Thank you,

Comment: This sounds like the kind of thing that is intentionally impossible. I don't think unprivileged code can change the browser config. But see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Communication_between_HTML_and_your_extension

Comment: Hi, We can configure is using cookies. But Best way is which you have have advised one.

Comment: It's not impossible but tricky - you should add handler that will react only on URL of your web and then you can do everything what you want.

Answer (score 0):

There are steps you should follow to do this:

- attach event handler to browser element that should be triggered when browser reach your site
- after this you have to attach event handlers for specific actions on this page (event handler for form submit for this case)
- that event handlers have access to chrome (your addon's preferences) so you are free to modify them.